# Trying to understand Race Conditions/Threads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

For staters, I am a student who wasn't a CS undergrad, but am moving into a CS masters. So I welcome any and all help anyone is willing to give.

The purpose of this was to create N threads between 2-4, then using a randomly generated array of lower case characters, make them uppercase.

This needed to be done using the N threads (defined by the command line when executed), dividing the work up as evenly as possible, using pthread.

My main question I'm trying to ask, is if I avoided race conditions between my threads?

I am also struggling to understand dividing the work among the threads. As I understand (correct me if I'm wrong), in general the threads functioning will be chosen at random during execution. So, I'm assuming I need to do something along the lines of dynamically dividing the array among the N number of threads and setting it so that each thread will perform the uppercasing of a same sized subsection of the array?

I know there are likely a number of other discrepancies I need to get better at within my code, but I haven't coded long and just started using C/C++ about a month ago.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <ctype.h>

//Global variable for threads
char randChars[60];
int j=0;

//Used to avoid race conditions
pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

//Establish the threads
void* upperThread(void* argp)
{
    while(randChars[j])
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex1 );
        putchar (toupper(randChars[j]));
        j++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex1 );
    }

return NULL;

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //Initializae variables and thread
    int N,randNum,t;
    long i;
    pthread_t pth[N];
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex1, NULL);
    char randChar = ' ';

    //Check number of command inputs given
    if(argc!=2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage: %s <enter a value for N>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }

    N = atoi(argv[1]);

    //Checks command inputs for correct values
    if(N<2||N>4){
        printf("Please input a value between 2 and 4 for the number of threads.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    //Seed random to create a randomized value
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("original lower case version:\n");

    for (i=0; i<61; i++)
    {
        //Generate a random integer in lower alphabetical range
        randNum = rand()%26;
        randNum = randNum+97;

        //Convert int to char and add to array
        randChar = (char) randNum;
        randChars[i] = randChar;
        printf("%c", randChar);
    }

    //Create N threads
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(pth + i, NULL, upperThread, (void *)i);
    }

    printf("\n\nupper case version:\n");

    //Join the threads
    for(t=0; t < N; t++)
    {
        pthread_join(pth[t], NULL);
    }
    printf("\n");

    pthread_exit(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This attempt is a fool's errand. All the threads are trying to modify the same object and will just keep stepping on each other. The result will be that your code will spend almost all of its time coordinating the threads and almost no time doing actual useful work.

Comment: I was afraid that maybe have been the case, as it seemed like they were all trying to do the same thing all together. Thank you though.

Comment: The threads are accessing the global variable `j` outside of any lock, which is a race condition.  If you want the threads to each operate on a different/disjoint subset of the array, the best way to do that is to pass each thread the minimum and maximum index values you want it to operate on; then each thread can run in parallel with no mutex required (and no race conditions since they aren't accessing any shared variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you provided is not a good multithreaded program. The reason is that your threads will constantly wait for the one which holds the lock. Which basically makes your program sequential. I would change your `upperThread` to

```
void* upperThread(void* argp){
    int temp;
    while(randChars[j]){
            pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex1 );
            temp = j;     
            j++;
            pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex1 );

            putchar (toupper(randChars[temp]));
        }

    return NULL;

}
```

This way your threads will wait for one that holds the lock until it extracts the value of `j` , increment it and release the lock and then do the rest of its operations.

The general rule is that you have to acquire the lock only when you deal with **critical section** or **critical data** in this case it is an index of your string. Read about critical sections and racing conditions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section)